# Add css and images to snap's cabal build?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-snap-framework

When I build my [snap](http://snapframework.com/) project, it does not include any of my static resources or templates.

My project structure is as follows:

```
site.cabal
\src
\snaplets
      \heist
           *.tpl
\static
       \css
           *.css
       \images
           *.jpg
```

Currently, I am deploying my binary to the server separately from my static files (which I simply copy over).

Is there a better way to do this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed your static files into the executable while still having things work as they should wrt the rest of snap.

Also, in Windows there's a "resource system" in PE files which lets you embed resources, but on Linux/Unix there isn't. So, using external files is the only reliable way to ensure that they are reachable on every platform.

Additionally, you might want to add or remove static files when users e.g. upload them, and that's not possible with embedded resources.

Comment: "You can't embed your static files into the executable while still having things work as they should wrt the rest of snap." Why not?

Comment: Because the `snap` library uses the file system to load its files (like Heist templates), and you can't really tell the whole `snap` library to use complex resource stream allocation calls instead.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but what does "complex resource stream allocation calls" mean, and why would it need to do such a thing? Is it because when files get bundled into the binary, the program would need to "fake" them being on the hard drive?

Comment: No, you simply need different file APIs when the files are embedded compared to when they are not, and snap uses normal file APIs, not suited for resource streams.

Answer (score 2):

For my most recent project I created a script called deploy.sh that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rf -fr ../myapp-deploy/*
cp -R dist/build/myapp/myapp log snaplets static ../myapp-deploy
```

Then I deploy everything in myapp-deploy.  This can be done a number of ways.  One approach is to zip it up and ftp/scp it to your deployment server.  Another approach that I like and have used in the past is to make myapp-deploy into its own git repository.  Then after I run deploy.sh, I commit everything in myapp-deploy and push it to some centralized repository.  Then on my deployment server I can do `git pull && killall -HUP myapp` to go live with the most recent version.  The benefit to having it in a git repository is that I can always revert back to the previous version very easily.  If you have dynamic filesystem resources created by your users, then this approach might not work as well for you.

At the end of the day, reliable production deployment is a complex problem that needs an individualized approach.  Something like this can be a useful guide, but can't replace the need for good IT engineering.

Comment: I do a similar thing, where I checkout that lastest git version onto my production, and then execute my compiled binary (which I rsync'ed to the server) in the context of my git repository directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed static files into your code using `Data.FileEmbed` found in [file-embed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed). I create a `res` directory and drop everything static in there. Then use the following code to access it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
-- src/Resources.hs

module Resources ( getResource, listResources ) where

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.FileEmbed

resources :: [(FilePath, BS.ByteString)]
resources = $(embedDir "res")

getResource :: FilePath -> Maybe BS.ByteString
getResource path = findResource resources
  where
    findResource [] = Nothing
    findResource ((p,cont):xs) = if p == path
                                    then (Just cont)
                                    else findResource xs

listResources :: [FilePath]
listResources = map fst resources
```

Then in the code where you define your routes, you create a list of `(route, handlers)`:

```
-- src/Site.hs
resRoutes :: [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
resRoutes = map f listResources
  where
    f res =
      (TE.encodeUtf8 $ T.pack res, (writeBS . fromJust) $ getResource res)

-- in your SnapletInit
app = makeSnaplet "app" "" Nothing $ do
  addRoutes resRoutes
  addRoutes otherRoutes
  return $ App ()
```

File `res/css/custom.css` in your file system is accessible via `http://<site>/css/custom.css`. This works with text files, and binary files like images.

You should note that the static files are "consumed" during compilation of `src/Resources.hs` so if you add, modify or delete resources you'll have to trigger a rebuild of that file.

---

I'm still looking for a way to build the Heist templates into the executable. Should be similar, only modifying how Heist looks up and reads the files, need to use the resource list instead.